# Building a recommendation system using word2vec

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

Now, from the outputs, I am unable to understand the embeddings or how these embeddings are changing or will change with new data.

Is this way correct for solving the problem statement and if so how can I optimize this to find the best embeddings for my dataset. Can anyone provide any suggestions on the same

Comment: I don't see any distinction in your examples of your corpus between 'symptoms' and 'diagnoses'. If any one word (or oddly `#hashprefixed` or `#hashbookended#`) coudl be either, that's ok, but a slightly different prediction problem. And, if your data is truly from a small, well-defined symptom vocabulary, word2vec may not be a very meaningful tool – you could just train other more discrete classifiers.

Comment: (Word2Vec would more likely be useful if facing a fuzzier set of natural-language descriptions, especially in adapting to newer words that might not exist in classified examples, but do exist in sufficient usage examples to train word-vectors that might help you determine similarities to other better-known words.)

Comment: @gojomo, Yes the #hashprefixed words signifies the diagnosis. Once I train the model, if I do topn=20, from the output (most similar symptoms and diagnosis), I am outputting the top few diagnosis as recommendations. The #hashprefixes are used to filter out only the diagnosis. Any flaw that you see with this approach? My data is not small as there will be around 30K sublists inside the corpus

Comment: What sorts of classifiers can you suggest. Given these are my only datapoints as provided in the example. The end goal is once I input a set of symptoms, I get a list of possible diagnosis with their probability/confidence score. How can I achieve something like that with this sort of a dataset without cosine similarity? Can you please help me understand if you have any such suggestions

Comment: Simple term-to-term cosine-similarity is likely to underperform actual classification algorithms, as they can do that, and far more. (Simple term-to-term similarity, and just looking at the one nearest diagnosis, is somewhat like a 'K-Nearest-Neighbors' classifier looking at only 1 neighbor.) I suggest treating the symptom lists/texts like texts, and trying various text-classification approaches – different feature-choices (bag-of-words, char-n-grams, multigrams, etc), & various simple classifiers – to see how well they doe before trying enhancements like word-vectors.

Comment: But classifiers are most likely to give me binary outcomes whereas I am looking for a set of similar/possible diagnosis from the input set of symptoms. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If I treat the symptom as texts, how do I use the diagnosis from there. I mean for example, if I have a set of 4 symptoms and 1 diagnosis in a list. How do I build a classifier with that data. Ofcourse there will be data of 30K other patients but how does that help. I have only 1 feature right which is the symptom. Any thoughts? Also can you please elaborate on why word2vec can fail in this case. Would be really helpful

Comment: You have text: some symptoms. You have a desired diagnosis: 1 of a fixed number of N possible classes. There are many ways to turn texts into feature vectors – I listed a few above – which can then be fed to many different classification algorithms, many which can do "multi-class classification", which typically gives some sort of ranked predictions with confidence scores. I'd recommend working text classification tutorials - skim through https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html & https://scikit-learn.org/stable/presentations.html for relevant stuff.