# Build a multiclass text classifier which takes vectors generated from word2vec as independent variables to predict a class

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, text-classification

I am dealing with patient data. I want to predict the top N diseases given a set of symptoms.

This is a sample of my dataset: In total I have around 1200 unique Symptoms and around 200 unique Diagnosis

```
     ID         Symptom combination                              Diagnosis
    Patient1: fever, loss of appetite, cold                        Flu
    Patient2: hair loss, blood pressure                           Thyroid
    Patient3: hair loss, blood pressure                            Flu
    Patient4: throat pain, joint pain                           Viral Fever

    ..
    ..
Patient30000: vomiting, nausea                                   Diarrohea
```

What I am planning to do with this dataset is to use the Symptoms column to generate word vectors using Word2vec for each row of patient data. After generating the vectors I want to build a classifier, with the vectors in each row being my independent variable and the Diagnosis being the target categorical variable.

Shall I take the average of the vectors to generate feature vectors generated from word2vec? If so, any clarifications on the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can average a bunch of word-vectors for symptoms together to get a single feature-vector of the same dimensionality. (If your word-vectors are 100d each, averaging them together gets a single 100d summary vector.)

But such averaging is fairly crude, and has some risk of diluting the information of each symptom in the averaging.

(As a simplified, stylized example, imagine a nurse took a patients' temperature at 9pm, and found it to be 102.6°F. Then again, at 7am, and found it to be 94.6°F. A doctor asks, "how's our patient's temperature?", and the nurse says the average, "98.6°F". "Wow," says the doctor, "it's rare for someone to be so on-the-dot for the normal healthy temperature. Next patient!" Averaging hid the important information: that the patient had both a fever and dangerous hypothermia.)

It sounds like you have a controlled-vocabulary of symptoms, with just some known, capped, and not-very-large number of symptom tokens: about 1200.

In such a case, turning those into a categorical vector for the presence/absence of each symptom may work far better than word2vec-based approaches. Maybe you have 100 different symptoms or 10,000 different symptoms. Either way, you can turn them into a large vector of 1s and 0s representing each possible symptom in order, and lots of classifiers will do pretty well with that input.

If treating the list-of-symptoms like a text-of-words, a simple "bag of words" representation of the text will essentially be this categorical representation: a 1200-dimensional 'one-hot' vector.

And unless this is some academic exercise where you've been required to use word2vec, it's not a good place to start, and may not be a part of the best solution. To train good word-vectors, you need more data than you have. (To re-use word-vectors from elsewhere, they should be well-matched to your domain.)

Word-vectors are most likely to help if you've gots tens-of-thousands to hundreds-of-thousands of terms, and many contextual examples of each of their uses, to plot their subtle variations-of-meaning in a dense shared space. Only 30,000 'texts', of ~3-5 tokens each, and only ~1200 unique tokens, is fairly small for word2vec.

(I made similar points in my [comments on one of your earlier questions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html).)

Once you've turned each row into a feature vector – whether it's by averaging symptom word-vectors, or probably better creating a bag-of-words representation – you can and should try many different classifiers to see which works best.

Many are drop-in replacements for each other, and with the size of your data, testing many against each other in a loop may take less than an hour or few.

If at a total loss where to start, anything listed in the 'classifiers' upper-left area of [this `scikit-learn` graphical guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) is worth trying:

[image: scikit-learn "choosing the right estimator"]

If you want to consider an even wider range of possibilities, and get a vaguely-intuitive idea of which ones can best discover certain kinds of "shapes" in the underlying high-dimensional data, you can look at all those demonstrated in [this `scikit-learn` "classifier comparison" page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html), with these graphical representations of how well they handle a noisy 2d classification challenge (instead of your 1200d challenge):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailing. I will go ahead and try with converting each row into a feature vector with an assigned class and let you know the outcome. After that I will also try the one hot encoding approach/bow that you had suggested and compare these 2 outcomes

Comment: I have a question. Over the period of time in my case, the symptoms and diagnosis labels will keep on growing. More and more new symptoms and diagnosis will keep on getting added to the dataset. What is the best way to handle those situations with this current approach in an automated way without much intervention going forward. Any idea on that?

Comment: Re-do the whole process with the new, expanded dataset, that includes new terms & diagnoses. You've got, comparatively, a tiny tiny amount of data. Re-running the whole process with the latest full dataset, & re-deploying the new model, shouldn't be onerous. Just be careful not to hard-code things prone to change – like creating dependencies on some opaque ordinal-numbers for tokens, that might change when the tokens/etc change in ordering/canonicalization/etc.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me with understanding how I can generate feature vectors for each row of my csv. So, for example in row 1 if I am having cough,cold,fever. From here, can I generate feature vectors for this combination together i.e 1 list alltogether for the 3 symptoms or do I have to separately take the vectors for cough, cold and fever i.e 3 separate lists

Comment: It depends on which strategies you've chosen to use to turn a row into features. You've already described one strategy: look up the word-vector for each word `'cough'` & `'cold'` and `'fever'`, then average them all together for one final vector. In contrast "bag of words" would mean that you instead create a 1200-dimensional vector, with all zeros, except in the positions for those three words, where you'd have ones. …

Comment: But in practice, you can just use `scikit-learn`'s `CountVectorizer`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer - with an `input` that's a list of all your space-delimited symptom strings, in order. (For example, `['cough cold fever', 'hair_loss blood_pressure']`.). And, the argument `binary=True`. so it's only using 0.0 and 1.0, rather than scaled counts as might be used in texts where words could appear more than once.

Comment: I have one query, can you please help me with this. My understanding is when I am trying to generate feature vectors for each row(combination of symptoms in my dataset), taking average of the vectors for 3 symptoms will perform logically similar to adding the vector for 3 symptoms to generate a 1D feature vector. Is my assumption correct? Or averaging the vector of 3 symptoms will perform differently from summing vector of 3 symptoms? I understand the magnitude will be different but want to understand if there will be any change in relations between vectors for these 2 different approaches

Comment: If unsure of which to do, the proper course is to alternately try both summing & averaging, and compare whether the results are better with one or the other. But if you haven't yet trained a classifier, that's a distracting minor detail. Pick either one & train a classifier.

Comment: Thanks..Do you have any examples/links of multiclass text classification using feature vectors?

Comment: The links I sent in my July 23 comment contain examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062583/building-a-disease-recommendation-system-using-word2vec#comment111520850_63062583 – the 1st link **is** a text-classification tutorial, the 2nd link is useful presentations/training, many of which include text-classification and other relevant classification examples.

Comment: Thanks. I could fit a basic classifier to my dataset. Any idea on how to choose the number of dimensions i.e size in the Word2vec parameter while training the model? I have just given size = 3 now for interpretation but doesn't seem the right way to do it. Or shall we take a 100 dimensional vector as word2vec gives by default and apply PCA to generate the dimension of feature vectors?

Comment: Also, one more point. When I am taking the average of word2vec to generate feature vectors, there might be a case where the average feature vector of a 4 symptom combination has the same feature vector of 1 symptom that is completely different. In that case, this is a flaw in logic. Any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: When you don't know the number of dimensions to use, and have a small dataset like yours where it is easy to try lots of alternatives, you should try many different sizes, & use whatever works best, & remember for later any patterns you observe. (But I'll note, '3' is an absurdly low dimensionality for "dense embeddings" like these, and '100', while it is the gensim `Word2Vec` default, *might* as a practical matter be too large for your relatively-tiny 1200-word symptom vocabulary.)

Comment: The fact that taking the average *might* cause some info to 'cancel out' is exactly the point of the 'simple, stylized' example above in my answer, and why averaging word-vectors might not be the best approach, and why I (and others) have repeatedly suggested you also try even simpler methods that might work better. But there's no harm in trying things that might or might not be the best, like averaging word-vectors, to score them against other approaches in the process of finding the best. But you have to try them; there's no way to just ask others for the best for your data/goal.

Comment: But also, it's premature to worry about "what if they average together to be same as another symptom", because: first, you've not yet ever seen that happen. (It might not – our intuitions from 1d, 2d, & 3d spaces can go awry in higher-dimensions about what's likely to happen. Read about "the curse of dimensionality".) And second: *if* it was appropriate to use word2vec at all, the whole point is to map things by similarities, alone or in certain relative combinations. If symptom A + symptom B is almost exactly symptom C, then *maybe* that's a useful real pattern in the data, not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. Yes, I will try the simpler approaches of generating vectors like bag of words or basic one hot encoding but the issue with that is dealing with class imbalance as I have an imbalanced dataset and that will continue to be the case. generating a 1D feature vector for any number of inputs through averaging/summing vectors helps in this case. I also want to try out summing the vectors and see what comes out. Maybe we can get around the issue of "what if they average together to be same as another symptom"

Comment: Do you think summing instead of averaging will be a better option? Also, if I generate a 100D feature vector from word2vec, will you suggest using something like a PCA on it to reduce the dimension or shall I just consider the 100D feature vector as 100 features to my classifier. I am sorry as these questions might appear really generalized but I really want to pick your brain's on these

Comment: If you training data is imbalanced, that will also be an issue with any word2vec vectors trained from that data. (The vectors for tokens with fewer occurrences will be far weaker than those for well-represented tokens, and the overall model's usefulness will be far more influenced by the more-represented tokens.) Also, the "what if they average together" issues isn't a real issue at all in practice, it's silly to worry about unless/until you see it in a real model.

Comment: I have no opinion on summing vs averaging until after you run it both ways, comparing the results, & reporting them. Similarly, no opinion on adding a PCA step. That extra work isn't usually done, but if you think it might help, you should absolutely try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the inputs. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you start without the word2vec and instead use a binary vectorizer. You will get a sparce binary matrix for your data. Then apply any of the multi-class classificators. Both are available from scikit-learn.

It is not clear how the vectors should add to the power of your model. They may be even counterproductive if the word2vec model is trained on an irrelevant dataset. Close vectors learned from that dataset may be actually representing contrasting symptoms for your target.

Comment: Yeah it's true that if we add irrelevant data, the vectors will be counterproductive. But the same thing will happen for a binary vectorizer also right? True that it's not really clear how the vectors are adding weights to the model internally

Comment: No, the binary vectorizer would only bring the information you have in the form the DecisionTree can handle. It would only encode the labels (symptoms) into binary code. No information lost and no added.